# My script works the first time and does anymore not after reload on this online IDE

Tags: javascript

I have a slight problem with this online code editor. When I launch my snippet, it only works one time. If I try to bring any modification to the code, it crashes for unknown reasons.

https://playcode.io/313059?tabs=console&script.js&output

Any clue of what is going on here?

Comment: We can't help you without explanation

Comment: Could you add the error you receive? What do you mean by "bring any modification to the code"? Make examples of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and I think that your code is executing while the editor is not loaded yet. Wait for the document or window to be loaded and then execute the code as following:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var block = document.getElementById('block');

      var block_scale = window
        .getComputedStyle(block, null)
        .getPropertyValue("transform");

      var matrix = block_scale.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/gm);
      console.log(matrix[0]);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is indeed the way to make it work. Did'nt think this would be required. Sorry for not being able to improve your answer's rating, my own points stock was suddenly downgraded under 15 because of this thread.

Comment: No worries ;) Glad it helped!